# Avoid repeating variable name in assignation

Tags: crystal-lang

I think I have seen a way to reduce this:

```
long_variable_name = long_variable_name.squeeze('i')
```

To something like this:

```
long_variable_name = &:squeeze('i')
```

But it doesn't work and I must be confusing.
Just wondering if there is actually a way to do this ?
Thanks

Comment: Is it ruby or is it crystal? Can't be both

Comment: Crystal. Actually I hoped it would be the same in both. I always look for both as ruby is more documented.

Comment: I'm curious why you need the string `long_variable_name`. What do you plan to do with it? (Perhaps it has something to do with *Crystal*, of which I know nothing).

Comment: Not very a long name but something like foo.bar.string

Comment: You can google for both, but don't tag crystal questions with "ruby" on stackoverflow. Those are different languages and different stdlibs.

Comment: I got it, thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

```
variable.squeeze!('i')
```

Note the bang (`!`).

Comment: In the String class, `!` denotes the in-place modifying version. See [`squeeze!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-squeeze-21).

Comment: In ruby, yes. Don't know about crystal :)

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for. Don't know why I remember this '&'. Thank you